# Safe way to implement matrix class with bracket operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am writing a bidimensional matrix class just for the sake of it, wrapping a vector of vectors.

Since matrices must have positive dimensions I make sure the matrix cannot be ill-constructed, and from then on I assume the matrix has at least one element:

```
Matrix2D::Matrix2D(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    if (rows == 0 || cols == 0)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Matrix cannot have zero as dimension");
    }
    ...
```

I want to offer the user a way of accessing and modifying particular elements by using the concatenated `[]` (i.e. `m[1][1]`). However, I don't want the user to be able to modify the dimension of the matrix or to modify the number of columns in one row. My current approach of offering the overloaded `operator[]` like below is not enough, since the user can use the non-const version (necessary for modifying particular elements) to modify the number of columns:

```
std::vector<double>& operator[](size_t r);
const std::vector<double>& operator[](size_t r) const;
```

by doing `m[0] = std::vector<double>(0)`.

**Is there a way of preventing this downfall while keeping the double bracket syntaxis?**

I am aware I could use `operator()` like `m(1, 1)`, but I'm curious about trying to use the double bracket syntaxis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator[]` can return a proxy object with `operator[]` defined. Something like this:

```
class Matrix2D
{
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> rows;

  class Proxy
  {
    friend class Matrix2D;

    std::vector<double> &v;

    Proxy(std::vector<double> &v) : v(v) {}

  public:
    double& operator[] (size_t c) const { return p[c]; }
  };

public:
  Proxy operator[] (size_t r)
  {
    return { rows[r]; }
  }
};
```

Note, however, that using a vector of vectors to represent a 2D matrix is usually a bad idea, as it's very cache-unfriendly. It would be much closer to practical usability if you store just one `std::vector<double>` of size `rows * cols` and index into it manually.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to let `Matrix::operator[](size_t)` return a proxy object, whose `operator[](size_t)` returns a (const) reference to the matrix element.

```
//untested
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

private:
    std::vector<value_type> _data;
    class Row
    {
        Matrix& _m;
        size_t  _row;
    public:
        Row(Matrix& m, size_t row) : _m(m), _row(row) {}
        value_type& operator[](size_t col) { return _m.at(_row, col); }
    }

public:
    // constructor(s) here
    value_type& at(size_t row, size_t col) { return /*...*/; }
    Row operator[](size_t row) { return Row{*this, row}; }
}
```

To be added: const versions, constructors, indexing, dimension handling. Once done, you'll be able to use it like this:

```
Matrix<double> m{/*...*/};
m[1][2] = 28;
auto row = m[1];
row[1] = 18;
//row = std::vector<double>(0); // ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

Peter Gottschling shows a template solution for `Matrix[][]` in his excellent book *Discovering Modern C++* (Addison Wesley 2016).  His method uses a proxy class as above and additionally the *Curiously Recurring Template Pattern* (CRTP).