# Overloading double subscript operator of std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I like to store a 3x3 Matrix as a `std::array<double,9>`. Furthermore, I like to overload the [][] operator, in order to access a component of the matrix like

```
using matrix = std::array<double,9>

matrix A {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
double A_11 = A[1][1];
```

I could easily wrap my matrix in a class and write a getter method like

```
double Matrix::get_component(int i, int j) {
    return A[3*i+j];
}
```

Nevertheless, this would spoil the readability of the code. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload) answer to a similar question, but I don't know how to adapt this to a fixed size `std::aray`.

Comment: Does it provide a satisfactory solution to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48297703/5470596 ?

Comment: There is no double-subscript operator.  What you show is two separate subscript operators, one applied to the result of the other.

Comment: Don't overload anything in std namespace. Make your own struct.

Comment: (unless it's explicitly allowed by c++ standard, or it's not release code)